# How to create permalink URL for API in WordPress?

Tags: json, wordpress

I use WordPress and list data from my API:

```
$url       = "http://example.com/all-list";
$response  = wp_remote_get( $url );
$data_body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

<?php foreach ( $data_body as $real_data ): ?>
   <a href="#"><h1><?php echo $real_data["title"]; ?></h1></a>
<?php end foreach; ?>
```

But in `<a href="#"></a>` I don't know how to give url.

Example: I'd like to give `<a href="/real-data?id=<?php $real_data['id'] ?>">` then return new view template. It like `get_permalink();` to view single page post.

How could I do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Check this examples below.

```
// This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar'
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' ) );

// This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar&baz=tiny'
$arr_params = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'tiny' );
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( $arr_params ) );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/